# Как рассчитать координаты по наклону?

Tags: python, pygame, геометрия

У меня есть координаты точки игрока (50, 100)
Идет отклонение на 10 градусов  оп часовой стрелке
[image: рисунок того как это выглядит]

мне нужно  посчитать координаты x и y конечной точки луча
при этом угол наклона, координаты игрока могут менятся и надо придумать как это сделать
Я програмирую на pygame
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

полная версия:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DFqnKnUzWxpLXdziHSZemKaGL7aHTIFp/view?usp=share_link
минимальная версия:
Main.py:

```
import pygame
import render
def run():

        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(500, 500)
        pygame.display.set_caption('3d game')
        while True:
            def run():
        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size['width'],screen_size['height']))
        pygame.display.set_caption('3d game')
        while True:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(0, 0, 500, 500))
            render.render_position(screen)
            pygame.display.flip()
    run()
```

render.py:

```
import camera
import pygame

renderCamera = camera.Camera(100, 350)
def render_position(screen):
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 30)
    #for angle in range(0, 350, 10):
#        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 70, 70), (renderCamera.x, #renderCamera.y), !тут проблема!)
```

camera.py:

```
class Camera:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Comment: @Brainsluggy а почему в _ответе_

Comment: Вот тут то вам и пригодится школьная геометрия

Comment: Код нужно добавлять текстом, а не скриншотом. [Почему в вопросе не следует выкладывать скриншоты кода/данных/ошибок?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: @nchistov Ошибся :) Можете добавить код файла прямо в вопросе? Читать и переписывать из скриншота сложно.

Comment: что придумать-то? Пифагор уже давным давно придумал, возьмите начальный курс геометрии.

Comment: у меня он только на гугл диске

Comment: Нет, так не пойдет. Нужен [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), демонстрирующий вашу проблему, в самом вопросе, а не весь ваш проект. Проблема у вас только в вычислении координат, весь ваш проект тут не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно ответ выше был непонятен...

```py
import pygame
import math

def get_pos(start_pos, distance, angle):
    rad = angle / 180 * math.pi
    return (\
     start_pos[0] + math.cos(rad) * distance,\
     start_pos[1] + math.sin(rad) * distance )
```

`start_pos` это `(число, число)` (кортёж или список двух чисел) 
`distance` это `число`
`angle` это `число`
внутри функции градусы переводятся в радианы т.к. это `sin` `cos` принимают в аргумент - угол в радианах)

а также из за перевёрнутой по y системы координат угол надо брать отрицательный

и кстати точка с нулевым углом находится справа

(при необходимости можно вычесть из `rad` - `math. pi / 2`)

не совсем понятен вопрос, в том плане какая именно точка нужна, так например в ответе чуть ранее взяли точку пересечения с границей о которой вроде не говорится в вопросе, я же взял точку на круге с радиусом `distance`

Answer (score 1):

Пусть начало луча `start`, угол наклона `Fi`, размеры экрана `width, height`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Единичный вектор направления

```
dx = Cos(Fi)
dy = Sin(Fi)
```

Параметрическое уравнение луча для справки (в коде не нужно):

```
//x = start.x + dx * t
//y = start.y + dy * t
```

Границы, в которые может упереться луч

```
if dx > 0 then
   bx = width
else
   bx = 0

if dy > 0 then
   by = height
else
   by = 0
```

Проверка на вертикаль или горизонталь

```
if dx == 0 then
    return ix = start.x,  iy = by

if dy == 0 then
    return iy = start.y,  ix = bx
```

В общем случае найдём параметры параметрического уравнения

```
tx = (bx - start.x) / dx
ty = (by - start.y) / dy
```

И возьмем точку пересечения с меньшим значением параметра

```
if tx <= ty then
    ix = bx
    iy = start.y + tx * dy
 else
    iy = by
    ix = start.x + ty * dx

 return ix, iy  //вот она, точка пересечения с границей
```